# How to use Go lang http client to submit http request to a SSO enabled server

Tags: go, saml, net-http

I am working on a Go script that makes some API calls to a webserver. I use the net/http library. SSO can be enabled or disabled on this webserver. So my go script works well with a non-SSO webserver. It is able to hit the endpoints. But with SSO, I get a http response like this 
    `

**Note:** Since your browser does not support JavaScript,
                you must press the Continue button once to proceed.

```
    <form action="https&#x3a;&#x2f;&#x2f;hostname&#x2f;idp&#x2f;SSO.saml2" method="post">
        <div>

            <input type="hidden" name="SAMLRequest" value="PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj......pBdXRoblJlcXVlc3Q+"/>

        </div>
        <noscript>
            <div>
                <input type="submit" value="Continue"/>
            </div>
        </noscript>
    </form>
        </body>
```

`
Is there a way in Go lang, to execute the form action and handle all the redirection?

Comment: SSO meaning what? OAuth? JWT? LDAP? NTLM? Something custom/proprietary?

Comment: We are using PingFederate and ADFS

Comment: I was able to move a little further by parsing the response with goquery and able to re-submit another request to the SSO SAML Url with the SAMLRequest. Now I'm seeing tls-negotiation error. I guess I should use the appropriate key/cert.

Comment: I was able to resolve the tls regenotiation error and now it reached a stage where I have to programmatically pass-in the credentials (here adfs username/password)